# Add fade effect on active bg

Tags: jquery, css, fade

I have a menu structure:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="button1" class="active"><a href="#page-1" title="creative">creativ</a><
   <li id="button1"><a href="#page-1" title="creative">creativ</a></ul>
```

And i add background image every `.active` class:

```
#nav li.active a{cursor:default;
                 background:url(images/nav-li-a_hover.png) no-repeat bottom center;
                 padding-bottom:5px;}
```

It's working. But i want when i click a menu item, get background-image with fade effect. How can i do this via jQuery or CSS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't use the same `id` on different objects, `id`'s must be uniqiue, use `class` instead. And one more thing; don't forgot to close html elements, there are no closing on your `li`s.

**Update:** If you want to only bg to fadeIn than you should seperate the elements. Create an element `s` inside `a` and than manipulate it like this:

```
$('ul#nav li').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('s').hide().addClass('.active').fadeIn(500);
});
```

True html:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li class="button1 active"><a href="#page-1" title="creative">creativ<s></s></a></li>
   <li class="button1"><a href="#page-1" title="creative">creativ<s></s></a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
#nav li.active s {background:url(images/nav-li-a_hover.png) no-repeat bottom center;}
```

Comment: Thank you Barlas, it's working but when i put your code my site and click a item, get menu item and active background via fade effect. I want only background image get via fade.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you can do something like this:

```
$('.menu_item').click(function() {
  $(this).fadeIn('slow', function() {
    //completed animation 
  });
});
```

But, if you are calling a new page this won't work as you desire because the content will be refreshed.

One way to work around this is to use an ajax request which, on success, will update a section of your page, and the navigation section won't be affected:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: {"data":data },
    success: function(response){
        //success code
        $("#content").html(response)
    },
    error: function(response){
        //error code
    }
});
```

Or you can do the fade when the new page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //actions
})
```

You will need to find out which button was pressed and do the fadeIn to it. That depends on the technology you are using, and on taste, but one way to do it is to place a var on the page with the selected menu item.