# Change fadeIn to slide

Tags: jquery, fadein, slide, fade

I have a menu structure:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="button1" class="active"><a href="#page-1" title="creative">creativ</a><
    <li id="button1"><a href="#page-1" title="creative">creativ</a>
</ul>
```

And I add background image every `.active` class:

```
#nav li.active a {
    cursor: default;
    background: url(images/nav-li-a_hover.png) no-repeat bottom center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

I added `fadeIn` effect on `active` class.

```
$('ul#nav li').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().addClass('.active').fadeIn(500);
});
```

But now, I want to change to slide effect. How can I do this?

Comment: FYI your `li` elements are missing their closing tags

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is perfectly valid syntax, btw :) But looks funny.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan told him that before, and id's should be uniqiue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14625806/1428241

Comment: @dfsq it's not valid syntax, an `li` must have a direct parent of `ol` or `ul`.

Comment: Hey friends, edit my div for valid syntax. Thank you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes it is. Some HTML closing tags are optional like `li` or `p`. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#didx-element-3

Comment: @dfsq ok perhaps they are valid in the strictest sense, however if you scroll up to section 3.2 in your link it has this line in it: `The appendix lists some SGML features that are not widely supported by HTML tools and user agents and should be avoided.`

Answer (score 0):

use slideUp method

```
$(this).hide().addClass('.active').slideUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

change fadeIn to slideDown and fadeOut to slideUp
a valid dom would be

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="button1 active"><a href="#page-1" title="creative">creativ</a></li>
    <li class="button1"><a href="#page-1" title="creative">creativ</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: change fadeIn  to slideDown and fadeOut to slideUp